# rollapply with function that returns more than one value

Tags: r, rollapply

Say I want to use rollapply with a function that returns more than on value. Like this:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO")

openYHOO <- YHOO[1:10,1]

rollapply(openYHOO, width = 2, range)
```

I get an error. 
I also tried merging the results inside the function:

```
rollapply(openYHOO, width = 2, function(x) {
  cbind(range(x))
})

rollapply(openYHOO, width = 2, function(x) {
  merge(range(x))
})
```

More errors.
I can do this:

```
cbind(
  rollapply(openYHOO, width = 2, function(x) {
    range(x)[1]
  }),
  rollapply(openYHOO, width = 2, function(x) {
    range(x)[2]
  })
)
```

...and it works.

However, what if I want to call `fivenum` or use something much more complicated  and computationally intensive in the fun argument? Do I have to call rollapply for each value that I want to return, generating the same object over and over again?

Am I missing something or should I abandon rollapply and roll my own rolling window function?

Can you explain why this `rollapply(openYHOO, width = 2, range)` does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `by.column` argument

```
rollapply(openYHOO, width=2, range, by.column=FALSE)
#            [,1]  [,2]
#2007-01-03    NA    NA
#2007-01-04 25.64 25.85
#2007-01-05 25.64 26.70
#2007-01-08 26.70 27.70
#2007-01-09 27.70 28.00
#2007-01-10 27.48 28.00
#2007-01-11 27.48 28.76
#2007-01-12 28.76 28.98
#2007-01-16 28.98 29.88
#2007-01-17 29.40 29.88

> rollapply(openYHOO, width=2, 
            function(x) fivenum(as.numeric(x)), 
            by.column=FALSE)
#            [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#2007-01-03    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA
#2007-01-04 25.64 25.64 25.745 25.85 25.85
#2007-01-05 25.64 25.64 26.170 26.70 26.70
#2007-01-08 26.70 26.70 27.200 27.70 27.70
#2007-01-09 27.70 27.70 27.850 28.00 28.00
#2007-01-10 27.48 27.48 27.740 28.00 28.00
#2007-01-11 27.48 27.48 28.120 28.76 28.76
#2007-01-12 28.76 28.76 28.870 28.98 28.98
#2007-01-16 28.98 28.98 29.430 29.88 29.88
#2007-01-17 29.40 29.40 29.640 29.88 29.88
```

Comment: This works. Thanks.  Not what I expect from the help document description of "by.column  logical. If TRUE, FUN is applied to each column separately." But the example in the doc does show the behavior I'm looking for.  Adapted for my example: `rollapply(openYHOO, width = 3, FUN = function(x) coef(lm(x ~ seq_along(x))), by.column = FALSE, align = "right")`